# Classification of these graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

Doing some research I am pretty sure the first graph is a square antiprism graph but I'm not sure about the second graph. 
In the second graph every intersection should have a "node" covering it, including the four corner points. To make the first graph into the second graph you have to add a lot more lines that "go across the box and connect opposite corners."

The second graph is a much more built up representation of the first graph. In the first graph every node has degree 4. **In the second graph every "interior" node has degree four and each of the 4 outer corners has degree 30**, but you can increase the degree of the 4 outer nodes by any amount by adding more edges. So by adding more edges and nodes the degree of the interior nodes stays constant at 4 while the degree of the outer 4 nodes increases. **Is there a name for this type of graph and has it been studied in the literature before?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah the inner 4-cycle becomes a 30 by 30 grid

Comment: node network; https://mathinsight.org/definition/network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a rectangular set of points (vertices) and connect horizontal or vertical adjacent vertices you get what is called a [Grid Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html). In your case, you add one extra vertex for each of the four sides of the rectangle and connect these new vertices to two adjacent vertices to form a four cycle and you also connect each new vertex to all the vertices of the corresponding side of the grid graph. I would call this an augmented grid graph, although at least one brief article has used that name for a grid graph with some extra edges between neighboring vertices but no new vertices.